# docker restart policy "always" not working with chaos engineer tool which kill the container randomly

Tags: docker

Below is my docker compose file, I added restart policy as always for every service. My expected behavior is that when the chaos engineer kill one of the containers, it would automatically restart. However, it now just exit and never restart. The tool I'm using for killing the container is pumba, I would add the log of it:

```
./pumba --interval=1m --random -l info kill --signal=SIGTERM "re2:^example-voting-app_vote"
INFO[0000] killing container                             dryrun=false id=5fe93ff11e5a6fbb9dc584848159341bc1fb710c747599fa03276f234a3faa19 name=/example-voting-app_vote_1 signal=SIGTERM
```

and the container log:

```
 vote_1    | WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
vote_1    |  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
vote_1    |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:80
vote_1    |  * Running on http://172.20.0.5:80
vote_1    | Press CTRL+C to quit
vote_1    |  * Restarting with stat
worker_1  | Connected to db
worker_1  | Connecting to redis
worker_1  | Found redis at 172.20.0.2
result_1  | [nodemon] 2.0.22
result_1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
result_1  | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
result_1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
result_1  | [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
vote_1    |  * Debugger is active!
vote_1    |  * Debugger PIN: 861-258-488
result_1  | Sun, 02 Jul 2023 00:48:49 GMT body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares at server.js:73:9
result_1  | Sun, 02 Jul 2023 00:48:49 GMT body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option at ../node_modules/body-parser/index.js:104:29
result_1  | App running on port 80
result_1  | Connected to db
example-voting-app_vote_1 exited with code 0
```

And my compose file

```
# version is now using "compose spec"
# v2 and v3 are now combined!
# docker-compose v1.27+ required

services:
  vote:
    build: ./vote
    # use python rather than gunicorn for local dev
    command: python app.py
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
    healthcheck: 
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    volumes:
     - ./vote:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
    restart: "always"

  result:
    build: ./result
    # use nodemon rather than node for local dev
    entrypoint: nodemon server.js
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy 
    volumes:
      - ./result:/app
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
      - "5858:5858"
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
    restart: "always"

  worker:
    build:
      context: ./worker
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy 
      db:
        condition: service_healthy 
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: "always"

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - "./healthchecks:/healthchecks"
    healthcheck:
      test: /healthchecks/redis.sh
      interval: "5s"
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: "always"

  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
    volumes:
      - "db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
      - "./healthchecks:/healthchecks"
    healthcheck:
      test: /healthchecks/postgres.sh
      interval: "5s"
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: "always"

  # this service runs once to seed the database with votes
  # it won't run unless you specify the "seed" profile
  # docker compose --profile seed up -d
  seed:
    build: ./seed-data
    profiles: ["seed"]
    depends_on:
      vote:
        condition: service_healthy 
    networks:
      - front-tier
    restart: "no"

volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:
```

Comment: How are you starting your compose?

Comment: @tadman I simply use docker-compose up